# .NET Entity Framework with Firebird: Error "Implementation limit exceeded. block size exceeds implementation restriction" with UTF-8 databases

Tags: .net, firebird, firebird2.5

I use the Firebird ADO.NET provider version 5.5 with the Entity Framework 5. With Firebird UTF-8 databases a LINQ to SQL query with a projection that includes conditionally setting a string property to a constant results in the error "Implementation limit exceeded. block size exceeds implementation restriction" if at least two of the mentioned string projections are present.

For example I query a simple database storing pizzerias:

```
var pizzerias =
    from pizzeria in demoEntities.Pizzerias
    select new
    {
        pizzeria.ID,
        pizzeria.Name,
        // Following two projections are the issue since Firebird add two times VARCHAR(8191) in case State and City are empty. 
        // It works with one of these projections, but not with two.
        State = pizzeria.State != "CA" ? pizzeria.State : "-",
        City = pizzeria.City != "Mountain View" ? pizzeria.City : "-"
    };
```

The two projections for State and City result in the aforementioned error (if only one projection exists the error does not occur).

The resulting SQL converts the string constants to VARCHAR(8191), which is most likely the cause of the error:

```
SELECT 
"A"."ID" AS "ID", 
"A"."NAME" AS "NAME", 
CASE WHEN (CAST(_UTF8'CA' AS VARCHAR(8191)) <> "A"."STATE") THEN "A"."STATE" ELSE CAST(_UTF8'-' AS VARCHAR(8191)) END AS "C1", 
CASE WHEN (CAST(_UTF8'Mountain View' AS VARCHAR(8191)) <> "A"."CITY") THEN "A"."CITY" ELSE CAST(_UTF8'-' AS VARCHAR(8191)) END AS "C2"
FROM "PIZZERIAS" AS "A"
```

When executing the SQL directly against the database (using IBExpert) the same error is thrown.

The strange thing is, that this error does not occur on an identical database that uses the Win1252 encoding.

By the way: I know that the projections in the sample do not make sense and that I could easily work around the problem. But I have a similar problem in a more complex scenario where I cannot work around so easy.

I want to understand what's happening here and why the problem does not occur on a Win1252 database. One solution would be to use a smaller VARCHAR in the projections, but I don't know how I could tell the ADO.NET Firebird provider to do this.

Comment: The cause of the problem is that a row can be a maximum of 64kilobytes, and this theoretically exceeds that maximum. Because 2 * max 8191 character * max 4 bytes per character, + 4 bytes for id (if it is integer, 8 bytes for bigint) + whatever the length is of name, and - iirc - 2 bytes per varchar for the length.

Comment: This explains the error, and the fact that with a Win1252 database the same query works (because of only one byte per character). For me the last question that remains is why the .NET provider converts string constants to VARCHAR(8191) anyway. The resulting SQL query works in Firebird even without the conversion.

Comment: I believe it does that to avoid problems when one of the cases  (or a comparison) is a parameter with a longer value than all the constants, as that would lead to the parameter being restricted to the length of the longest constant.